# Error writing Oracle BLOB into CSV using Python

Tags: python, oracle, csv, blob

I need to write the result of a sql query running against Oracle into a CSV file. The query successfully returns the data, but when trying to write the data into CSV I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 29, in <module>
    my_csv.writerow(row)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type bytes)
```

Code:

```
myfile = open(output_file, 'w')
my_csv= csv.writer(myfile , dialect='excel')
for row in cur:
    my_csv.writerow(row)
```

One of the columns is of class cx_Oracle.BLOB causing this issue.

I've tried converting to binary or use .read() attribute but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing the individual elements of the row list, and calling read() only on the BLOB columns, as shown below.  This example assumes an Oracle table with five columns where the first and fourth columns are BLOB's.

```
for row in cur:
    my_csv.writerow([row[0].read(),  # BLOB column
                     row[1],         # non-BLOB column
                     row[2],         # non-BLOB column
                     row[3].read(),  # BLOB column
                     row[4]])        # non-BLOB column
```